# Edge browser Websocket connection will be automatically closed after an idle time

Tags: websocket, microsoft-edge

I did a test about Websocket on new Window Edge browser.

It seems that the websocket connection on the Edge browser will be automatically closed after an idle time (no data transmission b/w 2 endpoints).
The issue does not happens on chrome or firefox.

I just wonder:
Is there any additional configuration when initializing the websocket connection on Edge browser to keep the connection opened?

I really dont' want to implement heartbeat mechanism because actually everything still works well on other browsers.

Answer (score 4):

This might not be the answer you want, but...

Most production environments for websocket apps run behind a Websocket Proxy (Apache, Nginx etc') that usually also acts as a load balancer.

These servers will also implement a 'timeout' mechanism that is needed to avoid `half closed` sockets (when only one side closed the connection and no data is transmitted, no error is raised and the file handle can be left open indefinitely).

For instance, [Heroku enforces a 55 second timeout window](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#timeouts).

This means you should probably set up a heartbeat anyway - even if your development app doesn't experience shutdowns.

If you're writing a server-side app and have control over the websocket, you should probably set up ping frames that won't cause an `onmessage` event to be raised (ping and pong frames have a different `op code` and aren't part of the regular message sequence).

Some websocket frameworks (such as Plezi on Ruby) will set up pinging automatically as a default option, but some servers / frameworks leave this up to you.

**To summarize:**

These disconnections WILL be the **expected behavior** (even a required behavior) for a **production environment**. Although it's also very likely to be an MS Edge issue, you will probably have to implement a heartbeat in both cases.

**P.S.**

The Websocket standard states that:

> Servers MAY close the WebSocket connection whenever desired.  Clients SHOULD NOT close the WebSocket connection arbitrarily.

Servers (and Websocket Proxies and load balancers) use this to establish their timeouts. **It's the client's responsibility to reconnect**.

MS Edge really shouldn't utilize a timeout, as this isn't the expected behavior according to the standard... although Edge might be doing it to make sure the connection is still open (by forcing the script to reconnect as a reaction to a server's arbitrary disconnection).

Comment: thanks! But if it's a problem of server configuration. Why does it still work on other browsers like chrome or firefox! Have you ever thought it is an bug of MS Edge ?

Comment: I didn't say it **IS** a server **problem** - I said it **WILL** be an **expected behavior** (even a _required_ behavior) for a _production environment_. It's **also** very likely to be an MS Edge issue, but you will have to implement a heartbeat in both cases.

Comment: @ChiếnNghê I updated my answer to reflect both my comment (my answer to your comment) and to point out that dropping the connection (usually due to timeout) is an expected server behavior you should prepare for in production environments.

Comment: Thanks you! I am using Netty to implement my websocket server. The idle time is set to 10 minutes. But it seems that the Edge have mechanism itself to implement autodisconnection, about every 20 seconds of idle time, the connection will be closed

Comment: On my ws server also produces exceptions with log "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.PongWebSocketFrame frame types not supported" (this doesnt happen on other browser but Edge). It's normally supposed that the server will receive PingWebSocketFrame instead and then response with a PongWebSocketFrame, but in my case, my server is getting a PongWebSocketFrame from client. Do you think it relates to my issue?

Comment: @ChiếnNghê - Actually, the server should be able to handle a `pong` frame. Both `ping` and `pong` frames can be sent by either side. In fact, server-side sent `ping`/`pong` are helpful to keep a websocket connection alive. If this is the issue, it's a Netty issue which should be fixed. I find it more plausible that Edge is sending a funky `pong` frame...  But you're intuition is probably right - It's very probable that the exception raised causes the connection to close.

Comment: @ChiếnNghê - Searching on google, it seems that [this might be an old issue with the server](http://atmosphere-framework.2306103.n4.nabble.com/Internet-Explorer-10-websocket-error-td4656614.html) not handling `pong` frames - I'm surprised. I think you should make sure you have the most updated Netty version. If you do, it might be best if you [opened an issue with Netty](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues).