# Microsoft Edge "WebSocket Error: Network Error 12030" using WebSockets after some inactivity

Tags: node.js, websocket, microsoft-edge

I am using WebSockets in a Web application. In Chrome and Firefox it all works. In the Edge browser, after some time of inactivity simply breaks the connection. And in the console appears the message:

> websocket error: network error 12030, the connection with the server was
>   terminated abnormally.

It is important for the application that the connection is permanent.

The following are parts of the server and the client:

**Server:**

```
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert/server.key')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert/server.crt'))
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);

wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});



// Handle Socket Request
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {

    try {
        // Do Stuff

        var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);

        // Do Stuff
    } catch(error) {
        console.log('Error during socket request: ', error);
    }

    // Handle Socket message
    connection.on('message', function(message) {

        try {
          // Do Stuff    
        } catch(error) {
            console.log('Error while receiving message: ', error);
        }
    });

    // Handle Socket disconnect
    connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {

        try {
            // Make sure to remove closed connections from the global pool
            delete clients[connection.location][connection.id];
        } catch(error) {
            console.log('Error while disconnecting socket: ', error);
        }
    });

});

// start server, listen to port
server.listen(49152, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 49152');
});
```

**Client**

```
// connecting to the web server
var socket = new WebSocket(socketProtocol + '://' + socketServer + '', 'echo-protocol');

// listening for server response
socket.onmessage = function (message) {

    // Do Stuff
};

// listening for any socket error
socket.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log('WebSocket error: ' + error);
};

// listening for connection to be open
socket.onopen = function (e) {
    console.log('connected');
};
```

Any ideas why this happens?

I've already thought about using socket.io and / or doing some sort of polling so the connection persists. But I hope there is a way that I do not have to change everything.

Comment: I still do not know why the connection is broken in Edge. But the following script helped, so that when a connection gets lost it will be automatically restored: https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket. The code had to be changed in only a few places.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edge browser Websocket connection will be automatically closed after an idle time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066963/edge-browser-websocket-connection-will-be-automatically-closed-after-an-idle-tim)